# Translation symmetry and Cauchy products

Tags: mathematics

I often meet the following situation:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0} ^\infty \sum\limits_{k=0} ^n f(k)g(n-k)=\sum\limits_{p=0} ^\infty \sum\limits_{q=0}^\infty f(p)g(q)$$

While intuitively this is very clear to me (and it's evident by brute force), I'm having problems to rigorously prove this. Could somebody please help me out?

So far my friends and I have come up with the map: $(n,k) \rightarrow (q,p) \text{ with } k\leq n$ where $q(n)=n-k$ and $p(n)=q+n=k$ Therefore we only need to prove  bijection.

Thanks

EDIT: The original problem was motivated by:

$$e^{(L_A+L_B)}=\sum\limits_{n=0} ^\infty \sum\limits_{k=0} ^n \frac{1}{k! (n-k)!} L_1^k  L_2^{n-k}=\sum\limits_{p=0} ^\infty \sum\limits_{q=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p! q!} L_1^p L_2^q=e^{L_A}e^{L_B}$$

where $L_A$ and $L_B \in \mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is a Banach space. However, I encountered the same problem when dealing with double Fourier transforms

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): One cannot always reorder double summations. See theorems of Tonelli and Fubini.

Comment: I do not understand your exponential of elements of a Banach space. Are $L_A$ and $L_B$ operators? Then the formula is correct if $A$ and $B$ commute but not in general.

Comment: I know the identity holds in that case. I only need the proof for the first equation given both series are absolutely convergent.

Comment: You still did not answer my question.

Comment: Sorry, yes, they are operators

Comment: And do they commute?

Comment: Yes, they commute but I would like to understand how commutativity comes into play here so that one can rearrange the double sum from the pair $(n,k)$ to $(p,q)$

Comment: commutativity comes into play via the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula At least, if the Banach algebra is also a Lie algebra.